# WPF проблема с CompositeCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Доброго времени суток!

Хочу объединить `ContextMenu` разных контролов. Как можно такое реализовать?
Пытался через `CompositeCollection`, но когда вызываю `ContextMenu` у `StackPanel`, а потом у `Button`, а потом снова у `StackPanel`, то у `StackPanel` пропадает `MenuItem`.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainMenuViewModel></local:MainMenuViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="mn">
        <MenuItem Header="Main Context" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"></MenuItem>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Background="Green" Height="100" Width="100" x:Name="myStackPanel">
    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=mn}"></ContextMenu>
    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
    <Button Content="Button" Width="120" Height="30">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource ResourceKey=mn}"/>
                        <Separator/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Child Context" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: Вот как получается.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MenuItem` не может одновременно принадлежать разным `ContextMenu`. Поэтому для решения данной проблемы нужно создать разные экземпляры `MenuItem`

```
<Window.Resources>

    <MenuItem x:Key="mainContext" Header="Main Context" x:Shared="False" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>

    <x:Array x:Key="mainContextMenu" Type="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Shared="False">
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="mainContext"/>
    </x:Array>

</Window.Resources>
```

Полный код:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainMenuViewModel></local:MainMenuViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>

    <MenuItem x:Key="mainContext" Header="Main Context" x:Shared="False" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>

    <x:Array x:Key="mainContextMenu" Type="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Shared="False">
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="mainContext"/>
    </x:Array>

</Window.Resources>

<Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=mainContextMenu}"></ContextMenu>
</Window.ContextMenu>

<Button Content="Button" Width="120" Height="30">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource ResourceKey=mainContextMenu}"/>
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Button Context" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```